# Visual Studio project load error : The attribute "Include" in element <EmbeddedResource> is unrecognized

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

When I open a project in visual studio I'm getting following error:

The attribute "Include" in element `<EmbeddedResource`> is unrecognized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the solution.

There was some problem in csproj file due to merging. Some files were added twice. That were causing the issue. After removing duplicates issue is resolved.

Comment: Likewise, in my case it was a missing </Reference> tag.

Comment: Merge changed the order of subitems for me.

Answer (score 3):

MSBuild and Visual Studio (2015, at least) also give this error if an `EmbeddedResource` element is missing its closing tag. Between the error message's spurious text about the `Include` attribute and its lack of a line number, this can take longer than it should to track down.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when mistakenly opening a .jsproj project in VS2015 that was created with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I believe I installed VS2017 to fix this. Grts